# Map enum to string value

Tags: java, enums, mapstruct

I'm using a recent version of `MapStruct`. I'm trying to map the values of the corresponding string values to the actual `enum` value.

For instance, this is my `enum`:

```java
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Accessors(fluent = true)
public enum Type {
  T1("SomeValue"),
  T2("AnotherValue");

  private final String label;
}
```

I have a `Java` type (`ForeignType`) with a field/member that receives the data (one of the string values in the `enum`): `SomeValue` or `AnotherValue`. Then I have a "controlled" type (`MyType`) and I would like to use in this one the actual enumeration constant (`T1` or `T2`), based on string value sent.

I'm looking for a way to use `MapStruct` to do this, because the application currently uses it for all mapping purposes, but so far I can't find a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapStruct has the concept of `@ValueMapping` that can be used to map a String into an `Enum`.

e.g.

```
@Mapper
public interface TypeMapper {


    @ValueMapping(target = "T1", source = "SomeValue")
    @ValueMapping(target = "T2", source = "AnotherValue")
    Type map(String type);


}
```

Doing the above MapStruct will implement a method for you. However, an alternative approach would be to use a custom method to do the mapping:

e.g.

```
public interface TypeMapper {

    default Type map(String type) {
        if (type == null) {
            return null;
        }

        for(Type t: Type.values()) {
            if (type.equals(t.label()) {
                return t;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot map label " + type + " to type");
    }

}
```